# Whats so special about the pikachu you get in pokemon home?

Tags: pokemon-home

I got pokemon home for the first time and i wanted to test it out. I saw a pikachu with a japanese nickname already put into one of the slots when i checked the home's box. It's not shiny or anything, and it doesnt seem to have any special moves/stats. Is there anything special about this pikachu other than the nickname?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from it being a free Pikachu, there is nothing really all that special about it.

- Can't Gigantamax
- Has a mediocre move set for a lv5 Pikachu
- Not shiny
- All IVs are "Pretty Good"
- Does not have the hidden ability
- Random nature